# Why for a zeroth-order logic is not possible to have a complete Peano arithmetic with quantifier free arithmetical sentences?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In my [previously question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451011/in-which-way-is-possible-to-rewrite-signature-of-peano-arithmetic-in-a-zero-orde) I still have some doubts and in particular about this part

> Peano arithmetic is impossible to rewrite into zero-order logic since Peano arithmetic has functions like the successor function.

But I still don't understand what is special about this successor function to prevent eliminating quantifiers and making it zero-order.

I need to have some clarifications regarding Peano's arithmetic.  Here is a list of questions taken from the comments from my last answer.

1. **Why no successor function gets described in the formation rules**?

Answer or Doug is not so clear for me, he says

*There exist propositional variables and connectives only.
The formation rules end with a clause something like "nothing else is a well-formed formula." No successor function gets described in the formation rules, so no successor function exists in zero-order logic*

Can you write me an example to show this?

2. **Why zeroth order logic has implicit universal quantification**?

Doug says

*axiomatic propositional calculus has implicit universal quantification over propositional variables, thus implicit universal quantification exists in axiomatic propositional calculus). So, the only question lies in how to get rid of existential quantifiers. Skolemization is the process for that*

Can you explain better about "implicit universal quantification" ?

User21820 reply that " *Skolemization is irrelevant*"

Question: **Why is irrelevant**?

User21820 says then "*You simply cannot do quantifier reasoning without quantifiers. Skolemization does nothing to help that*"

But why you simply cannot do..? Why does it mean "**simply cannot**"?

3. **What is this "schema" and what is that "numeral naming number n**" ?

Mauro says

*We can codify the infinite list of axioms as a schema in the meta-language: 0≠s(n¯¯¯))0≠s(n¯)) where n¯¯¯n¯ is the numeral naming number nn*

4. **Why zero-order system with addition need not be complete**? 
   What does it mean that not necessarily provable .. ?

Doug says

*zero-order system with functions such as addition, multiplication, mathematical induction, etc. need not be complete. Every true statement in its semantics is not necessarily provable in the usual calculi*

Thank you for any help, but I'm a tough head.

Comment: But in your previous post you have the quote "... the unary successor operation S..." So, it is part of the language sketched by Tao for the zeroth-order arithmetic.

Comment: to 1) Thus, having all the *numerals*: $0,1,2,\ldots$ as constant **and** the *successor* function $s$, as wella s the two operations: $+, \times$, we can build "complex terms like $s(0)+1$ and sentences like $s(0)+1=2$.

Comment: to 2) there is no ""implicit universal quantification" because there is no quantifiers at all and there are no individual variables: $x,y,\ldots$. The only way to express "generality" is trough *schema* in the meta language.

Comment: to 3) What is a *schema*? See [Schema](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/schema/): is the standard way used in the presentation of logical system; see the Modus Ponens rule: $\dfrac {\varphi \ \ \varphi \to \psi}{\psi}$ where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are formulas of the language. Here $\varphi,\psi$ are not symbols of the language but meta-variables referring to expressions of the language.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA So if we can express "generality" is through the schema in the metalanguage the successor function can be expressed as a unary successor operation S (like Tao sketched)? Same thing for the induction rule, I guess. But then why is it insisted that Peano's arithmetic must be first-order logic? Even if I don't write it with quantifiers and variables in zero order logic I know that is Peano's arithmetic because I now have a shema that generalizes first order logic to me. I guess I don't need to know that 1 + 1 = 2 using implicit universal quantification. Where I wrong?

Comment: I read also that "*Successor operations are also known as zeration in the context of a zeroth hyperoperation: H0(a, b) = 1 + b. In this context, the extension of zeration is addition, which is defined as repeated succession*." I don't see what the problem is in rewriting Peano's arithmetic in zero order logic. The binary operation is essentially reduced to a unary operation, the quantifiers are eliminated, but what I now have is the metalanguage that allowed me to generate this "logical cleaning" allowing me to represent in a zero-logic

Comment: Ok, I read now Gentzen's consistency proof and the difference with Presburger arithmetic that is decidable arithmetic (Zeroth-order logic (propositional logic) is decidable, whereas first-order and higher-order logic are not). Here problem seems to be another: Is axiom schema of induction and not successor function that make a Peano Arithmetic a first-order logic ?

Comment: Not clear at all... In the sense used in Tao's book Zeroth-order logic is **not** propositional logic. "Is axiom schema of induction and not successor function that make a Peano Arithmetic a first-order logic ?" NO, it is the language of predicate logic: variables, constants, predicate symbols, quantifiers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA ok, but if is not a propositional logic and it is zeroth-order logic the  incompletess theorem is still valid for a Peano Arithmetic with Tao version? Because I know that incompletess theorem it works for a first-order logic of PA version, I don't know if that theorem is applicable for a PA with Tao's book Zeroth-order logic version

Answer (score 0):

To encode the successor function, you can have infinitely many axioms, namely that $0 + 1 = 1$, $1 + 1 = 2$, $2 + 1 = 3$, $3 + 1 = 4$, etc.

Suppose you want to prove in your zeroth order axiomatization of Peano Arithmetic that multiplication is commutative. In first order logic, you can use universal quantification explicit, and state the commutativity of multiplication as $\forall x, \forall y, x\times y = y \times x$. However, in zeroth order logic, you will need to write down infinitely many statements, namely $0\times 0 = 0 \times 0$, $0 \times 1 = 1\times 0$, $0 \times 2 = 2\times 0$, ..., $1 \times 0 = 0 \times 1$, $1 \times 1 = 1\times 1$, $1 \times 2 = 2\times 1$, ..., ....

Comment: Is it not possible to encode this infinite sequence in a metalanguage?